# Comparing integers in different JSON response Arrays with Postman test

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman, postman-testcase

I have 2 different JSON responses from 2 different GET methods from postman.

I am trying to write a test to compare them.

the first response is `specificYield`

```
[
    [
        "2020-11-30T00:00:00Z",
        50.701604514154944
    ],
    [
        "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        19.328539610238128
    ],
    [
        "2021-01-31T00:00:00Z",
        25.183636870929693
    ]
]
```

The second response is `expectedYield`

```
[
    [
        "2020-11-30T00:00:00Z",
        62.78336503569246
    ],
    [
        "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        32.97678871921154
    ],
    [
        "2021-01-31T00:00:00Z",
        40.82916109964013
    ]
]
```

I am trying to check that the integer value in the `expectedYield` array is always greater than the value in the `specificYield` array

so it will compare the 62.78336503569246 to 50.701604514154944

and then 32.97678871921154 to 19.328539610238128

and so on

The test looks like this so far, but I know im not using objects anymore and am trying to refactor it to just work with arrays.

```
pm.test("Expected Yield > Specified Yield", function () {
  const expectedYield = pm.response.json();
  const specificYield = pm.globals.get("specificYield");
  Object.values(expectedYield).forEach((record) => {
    pm.expect(record[0][1]).to.greaterThan(
      Object.values(specificYield).forEach((record) => {
        pm.expect(record[0][1]);
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: There are no integers. The numbers have decimal points, so they're floating point.

Comment: Do you need to compare every number in one array with every number in the other array? Or just compare the corresponding elements with each other?

Comment: If you want to test if something is true for all array elements, use `Array.every()`.

Comment: @Barmar just to compare the corresponding floats variables

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PostMan syntax, but the standard JS syntax would be

```
expectedYield.every((record, i) => record[1] > specificYield[i][1])
```

The second argument `i` to the callback function is the index of the element being tested. This is used to compare that record with the corresponding record of the other array.

Then we use `every()` to check that it's true for the entire array. There's no need to use `Object.values()` -- that's used to convert the properties of an ordinary object to an array in order to use array methods, but these are already arrays.